# Do some transforms apply to text and not rectanges?

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, cytoscape.js

I'm working with a javascript library (Cytoscape) which draws onto an HTML canvas.

The source code uses several transforms to account for zoom and panning etc.

The trouble I'm having is that some text I'm drawing on using `context.fillText` is drawing inconsistently, it moves around on the screen depending on different conditions.

You could attribute this to a canvas transform being in effect, but for some reason `canvas.fillRect` is not affected.

eg, if I have two lines of code:

```
context.fillText("aaaa", 900,900);    //Acts inconsistently, changes relative size and position
context.fillRect(920, 920, 20, 20);   //Doesn't change at all.
```

Is there a setting on the canvas context that I'm missing that could be causing this effect, that affects text only, and not `fillRect`?

Comment: Do you have an example of this? Maybe a [codepen](http://codepen.io/) or [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: @Ouroborus Unfortunately not - because I'm working with modifying the source code of this library, it seems too complicated to create a jsfiddle for it.

But I will have a look at doing a sandbox just to check that my understanding of transforms is correct.

Comment: I don't know cytoscapeJS, but native html5 canvas transformations will affect `fillRect` and `fillText` identically.

Comment: @markE Yeah - that's what's driving me up the wall.

Comment: (1) Make sure you're setting font style.  (2) Make note of when transforms have happened and make your calls consistently w.r.t. the transforms.  (3) If you have trouble reading the code, use the debugger and step through instead

Answer (score 0):

`context.textAlign` and `context.textBaseline` will affect placement.

Comment: This hasn't explained the resizing issue though. At this point I've solved my problem and I might not look further.